# I am getting the following error while creating the ember application through cmd

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js

I am trying to create an ember application through command prompt

I installed Nodejs version v10.16.0 and then I used the command `npm install -g ember -cli` to install ember. ember successfully installed with version ember-cli 3.10.1.

Then I created a new application by using the command `ember new ember-quickstart`. Then I got the below error:

```
Error creating new application. Removing generated directory `./kushi`
Command failed: npm install --loglevel error
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4:  As of Babel 7.4.0, this
npm WARN deprecated package has been deprecated in favor of directly
npm WARN deprecated including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
npm WARN deprecated features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
npm WARN deprecated (needed to use transpiled generator functions):
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated import "core-js/stable";
npm WARN deprecated import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
npm WARN deprecated exists-sync@0.0.4: Please replace with usage of fs.existsSync
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\broccoli-rollup-93db1951\dist\index.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\broccoli-rollup-93db1951\dist\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\js\blueprints\ember-cli-typescript\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\js\lib\commands\clean.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\js\lib\commands\precompile.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\js\lib\utilities\copy-declarations.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\js\lib\utilities\ember-cli-entities.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\js\lib\utilities\fork.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\blueprint-files\ember-cli-typescript\__config_root__\config\environment.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no 
such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-typescript-b54d1b7c\blueprint-files\ember-cli-typescript\types\__app_name__\index.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-5cfc18ea\blueprints\module-unification-app\files\src\ui\routes\application\template.hbs'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-5cfc18ea\lib\tasks\server\middleware\broccoli-watcher\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-5cfc18ea\lib\tasks\server\middleware\broccoli-watcher\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-5cfc18ea\lib\tasks\server\middleware'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\Desktop\kushi\node_modules\.staging\ember-cli-5cfc18ea\lib'
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE
npm ERR! The value "false" is invalid for option "readableHighWaterMark"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\kagrawal.EMEAAD\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-02T09_36_58_880Z-debug.log
Stack Trace and Error Report: C:\Users\KAGRAW~1.EME\AppData\Local\Temp/error.dump.4edeef2bba53a9733909115d695aa4ba.log
```

Can someone help me to resolve the error?

Comment: Could you please format the output correctly? The line breaks are missing and therefore it's very hard to read.

Comment: Does `ember -v` give any errors? Did you look at the log file mentioned at the end of your posted error message, maybe it contains additional hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ola @dhS,

I notice in your answer you say that Ember doesn't support Node 10, that isn't true. The Node support for Ember is usually determined by what it is tested with and current the Continuous Integration (CI) is being run with Node 8, 10, 11, and 12.

You probably have a permissions issue or potentially some issue with your npm install that is reasonably hard to diagnose without the contents of the file that is listed at the end of that error:

```
Stack Trace and Error Report: C:\Users\KAGRAW~1.EME\AppData\Local\Temp/error.dump.4edeef2bba53a9733909115d695aa4ba.log
```

Next time you have an error like this it would be super helpful to have the contents of this file

Also, most of the error that you posted were warnings that could potentially have something to do with permissions issue on your computer  If you ever come across this again it might be worth **upgrading** your Node version or reinstalling it and also making sure that you are on the lastest npm version by running:

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

The professional fix to this problem

Check your npm version by running : npm -v

once you found the version you running , confirm this version by checking your package.json , and check the engines ... you will see npm and node versions required for the project.

upgrade your npm version to the one that is reflected on the package.json